# OpenLDAP Email Aliases Attribute

Tags: email, alias, openldap, aliases

I'm doing synchronisation of users between various LDAP's (MS AD, Azure AD, Google Apps, OpenLDAP) 
Obviously it's a custom solution

Got here a problem with mail aliases
for example, in Azure or MS AD attribute which store all other mail alias is named as "proxyAddresses", in Google Apps it is "aliases"

but in OpenLDAP I can't find a property with such names or anything similar...

It seems I'm missing some ObjectClass from my LDAP schema, but I can't find what objectClass exactly and what it attribute name used in OpenLDAP for storing email aliases

Any idea?
Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`inetOrgPerson` has a `mail` attribute, and it can be multi-valued.

Comment: Unfortunately "mail" is used for the primary mail. in OpenLDAP nearly all attributes are type of "list" and support multiple values, even "uid" but it doesn't mean that it logically correct to use them in such way. Anyway "mail" is clearly not aliases attribute

Comment: It doesn't mean it *isn't* logically correct either. I've been using it this way for 11 years.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found what I was looking for...

I connected MS Outlook and Thunderbird to our OpenLDAP to use it as Address book.
When I open contact - there are available fields for the main email and for alias:

For Ms Outlook GUI: last tab "Email Addresses"
For Thunderbird GUI: "Additional Email"
However, it doesn't say from which LDAP attributes it populate this data, so I had to use TCP dump on DLAP server to capture network request package from both of them

So... the answer is:
MS Outlook looking for aliases in LDAP attribute: "otherMailBox" which is part of "extensibleObject" objectClass

With thunderbird it is more complex, they expecting to have installed their custom schema "[mozillaOrgPerson](ftp://ayun.cmcc.ufro.cl/home/bk/www/ctt.ufro.cl/proyectos/addressbook/doc/mozillaorgperson.schema)" and alias it looking for in attribute "mozillaSecondEmail"

What is interesting "mozillaSecondEmail" can take list of values, however, Thunderbird will pick up in contact only first value, but, during email writing it can look up and find all others [according to this thread](https://lists.inverse.ca/sogo/arc/users/2014-03/msg00272.html)
 I'm still in the testing process of it and can't confirm for sure yet!

But ideally, the answer is "**otherMailBox**" from "**extensibleObject**" objectClass

Comment: It isn't part of `extensibleObject`. `extensibleObject` is just a magic class to which you can add any attribute at all.